# Image not visible in RSS feed

Tags: windows-phone-7, rss, listbox, itemssource, imageurl

I am developing a Windows phone app where the rss link is given in the app. The news result is displayed properly but the images are not being displayed. This is how i displayed the image in xaml

```
 <ListBox Name="feedListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="528" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="439" SelectionChanged="feedListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                            <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"  />
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="24" Name="feedTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Text="{Binding Title.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" />
                            <TextBlock Name="feedSummary" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Summary.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" />
                            <TextBlock Name="feedPubDate" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Margin="12,0,0,10" Text="{Binding PublishDate.DateTime}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

and in .cs this is how i retrieve

```
img = feed.ImageUrl;
feedListBox.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
```

how do i get the images in my app?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly do `img = image` as it's a template for each list item, not a certain image on a screen. Try to use a converter to transform Url from your feed into an Uri object:

```
public class UrlToUriConverter: IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new Uri(value.toString(), UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Edit: More info:

1. Create an UrlToUriConverter converter as above.
2. Insert that converter into your page resources:

   ```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
       <src:UrlToUriConverter x:Key="UrlToUri"/> </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
   ```

`src` is a namespace of the converter and it should be added in `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage` tag, eg. `xmlns:src="clr-namespace:TestProject"`

1. Use that converter in Image.Source binding:

   ```
           <Image Source="{Binding LineOne, Converter={StaticResource UrlToUri}}" >
   ```

Comment: so now how should i go about it?

Comment: There is nice example on MSDN Binding.Converter Property page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx

Comment: I added soome more info to my answer. Hope it will be helpful.